# Transfer information between asp.net and WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, awesomium

What I am trying to do is a bit complex:

I have a web site developed in asp.net, this site is displayed in a desktop application which was developed in WPF, the browser used to show this site is awesomium.

I need a way for one of the C# classes in the asp site (back end) to ask for information from the WPF application and get a response. all of the information is simple string.

A big plus (but not a requirement for the solution), in the site there are a few pages + I will need to add this implementation in other sites that I will build in the future so if there is a solution that does not affect the front end or the html file that will be helpful since it will prevent a dependency between the front end and this code.

Comment: Why not just post/get directly from the ASP site?

Comment: You mean: WPF call the ASP.NET page and get the response or viceversa ? Either from WPF you can call asp.net service (wcf, asmx) or from ASP.NET you can post/get

Comment: I edited it so it will be a little clearer but the idea is that the user presses a button on the site, this gives a command to the WPF with a parameter of type string and gets back a parameter of type string which it uses in the site.

Comment: Implement SignalR hub at the site, and write hub client at the WPF side. The phrase, that confused me, is "a solution that does not affect the front end or the html file". Whatever you choose, it requires some changes in WPF client and ASP.

Comment: The issue that confused you was that I want to make the changes in one cs file only (adding files is not a problem) so I don't have to start going over each page and making changes.
Thank you, I will try that.